# How to I direct to a new VIEW from AJAX call with JSON Object

Tags: javascript, ajax, datatables, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a view that shows all of the employees in a datatable.  I could just get the ID of the current row clicked, send to an actionresult function and then open the view by fetching it again.

But what I want to do is just use the data in the row instead of getting the data again with a query to the database.  Everything I need is in the datarow.

All of this works as expected with the exception...it isn't redirecting to the individual employee detail view.

I need to pass the datarow object which is why I'm using ajax.

What am I missing?

Controller:

```
[Route("GetEmployeeByObject")]
        public IActionResult GetEmployeeByObject(object? emp)
        {            
                var obj = emp.ToString();
                EmployeeDTO dto = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EmployeeDTO>(obj);
                EmployeeDetailViewModel employeeDetailViewModel = new(dto);
                return View(employeeDetailViewModel);                
        }
```

Javascript when the edit button in the datarow is clicked:

```
//individual record event
    $('#employee_table tbody').on('click', '.editLink', function () {

        var emp = employee_table.row($(this).parents('tr')).data();
        $.ajax({
            url: "Employees/GetEmployeeByObject/",
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify(emp),
            traditional: true,
            success:  function(data){
            //I don't want the code here because I want it to just load the employee view.
            }
        });
    });
```

Everything works.  But I need it to not RETURN to the page but redirect to the individual employee detail page.

Answer (score 0):

In your situation, I don't suggest you to use ajax, Because you can't use ajax to redirect to new individual page directly, I suggest you to use `form submit`, each row as the form and when user click button, It will submit the row data to action and just return view directly. But if you still want to use ajax, Here is two methods. The first one is in `GetEmployeeByObject` action, you need to return the `url` of the new individual page which you want to redirect instead of `return view(xxx)` directly:

```
return "xxx/xxx?property1='xxx'&property2='xxxx'";
```

Then in ajax success method:

```
success:function(response) {
               if(response){ // check whether response is received
                    window.location.href = response;}
               }
```

The second method is still `return view(xxx)` in backend, Then in ajax success method:

```
success: function(response){
                    document.write(response)
                }
```

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I don't think you can send just a single row that's been populated using json as a form.  Sending the ID field not with AJAX works but I'm just looking to not go back to query the DB again if I don't have to.

Comment: ok @Tamara Pattinson, Have you checked the methods i provided which redirect in ajax, I think it is what you want.